# Side Slide Out Menu - Potential Viewport/Overflow Problems

Tags: jquery, html, css, overflow, viewport

What is the best method for stopping a user on a mobile device from being able to scroll horizontally? I am attempting to have a "slide-out" menu, that upon opening pushes all content within the body aside. Using `overflow: hidden` does not appear to have an affect.

Currently, in mobile resolution (testing on iPhone/safari) the user is able to scroll right, revealing the menu before tapping the "open" button. Therefore, the menu does not appear hidden to the user.

I have not been able to test on other mobile devices, other than the iPhone.

The current meta tag in use:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale = 1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

A link to the live example, [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwierzba/xv3n257x/).

Comment: have you tried to use display css to none before the click on the open and upon clicking dynamically change the display ?

Comment: you can also try <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height">

Answer (score 0):

support for the overflow property is sometimes iffy is mobile browser support. hence users can still see the div if the browser does not support the overflow: hidden property.

I propose to hide the div with display:none and then inside the script, change the display as needed.

here is a snippet..

```js
var body = $('body');
var button = $('#button');
var menu = $('#menu');
var menuWidth = $('#menu').width();
var closeMenu = $('#menuClose');

menu.css({
  right: -menuWidth
});
button.html('Open');

function menuOperation() {
  event.preventDefault();

  if (body.css('right') == '0px') {
    body.animate({
      right: +menuWidth
    }, 600);
    button.html('Close');
    button.css('background', 'rgba(203,203,203,1)');
    menu.css('display', 'block'); /* added this */
  } else {
    body.animate({
      right: 0
    }, 600);
    button.html('Open');
    button.css('background', 'rgba(192,59,84,1)');
    menu.css('display', 'none'); /*added this */
  }
}

button.on('click', function(event) {
  menuOperation();
});

closeMenu.on('click', function(event) {
  menuOperation();
});
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600);
 body {
  width: 100%;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: rgba(236, 236, 236, 1);
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
  /*changed this */
}
#button {
  width: 125px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  background: rgba(192, 59, 84, 1);
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 15px;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}
@media(min-width: 321px) {
  #button {
    width: 100px;
    height: 22px;
    padding: 8px 0 10px 0;
    font-size: 16px;
  }
}
#menu {
  width: 300px;
  height: 650px;
  background: rgba(24, 24, 24, 0.95);
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  display: none;
  /*changed this */
}
#menu > div:first-child {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 22.5px 0;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: right;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  direction: rtl;
  text-indent: 70px;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.8s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.8s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.8s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
}
@media(min-width: 321px) {
  #menu > div: first-child {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
#menuClose {
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  border: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
  border-radius: 35px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
}
#menuClose > span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 17.5px;
  right: 0;
  left: 7.5px;
}
#menuClose > span:first-child {
  width: 20px;
  height: 1.5px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  display: block;
}
#menuClose > span:last-child {
  width: 20px;
  height: 1.5px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="button"></div>
<div id="menu">
  <div>Close Menu</div>
  <div id="menuClose">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

also try changing youe meta tag to

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height">
```

Hope this helps...

**update::**  check out the browser compatibility for mobile section here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow